# pass image id into form and submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a few images on a page. Each image has an id value assigned. I need to get image id, pass it into a form and submit that form when the image is clicked.

```
<IMG SRC="img1.gif" id="var1">
<IMG SRC="img2.gif" id="var2">

<form method="post" id="myForm" action="thisPage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="myID">
</form>
```

How do I pass the value from image into form?

Now, I do know I can use ajax with jQuery, but in this case I actually need to submit to this page and reload it after submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

still you can use jQuery without ajax.

```
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        $('[name=myID]').val($(this).attr('id'));
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

see demo. http://jsfiddle.net/gwgCH/3/

Comment: If you use jQuery then you will have a cleaner HTML. I did't altered your HTML code

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am starting to use jQuery a lot more and I love how I can expand my HTML functionality while keeping it clean. +1 for jsfiddle!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setImage(imgid) {
  document.getElementById('formImage').value = imgid;
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
}
</script>

<IMG SRC="img1.gif" id="var1" onclick="setImage('var1');" />
<IMG SRC="img2.gif" id="var2" onclick="setImage('var2');" />

<form method="post" id="myForm" action="thisPage.php">
<input type="hidden" id="formImage" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A javascript solution

```
<IMG SRC="img1.gif" id="var1" onclick="setid(this.id)">

function setid(id)
{
  document.getElementById('myID').value=id;
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```